# Create WordPress theme:

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to create an option panel WordPress theme. The option page  displays fine but on submit of form I get:

> ERROR: options page not found.

This is my code.

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Option Man
Description: A test plugin to manage site 
Author: Pravin Mishra
Version: 0.1
*/
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');
function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Option-Man-Plugin', 'Option Man', 'manage_options', 'test-plugin', 'test_init' );

}

function test_init(){

    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_setting' );

function register_my_setting() {
    //register_setting( 'myoptions-group', 'my_option_name', 'intval' ); 
    register_setting(‘myoptions-group’, ‘testplugin_option1′);

    register_setting(‘myoptions-group’, ‘testplugin_option2′);
} 
 echo "Hello world!";
 ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <u><h2>BS3 Custom Options</h2></u>
        <form method="post" action="http://192.168.2.139/web/wp-admin/options.php">
        <?php //settings_fields( 'myoptions-group' );
        //do_settings_sections( 'myoption-group' );
        settings_fields( 'myoptions-group' );
    ?>
<input type="text"   name="testplugin-option1" value="<?php echo get_option('testplugin_option1'); ?>"/>
<input type="text"  name="testplugin-option2" value="<?php echo get_option('testplugin_option2'); ?>"/>


    <?php
   submit_button(); 
            ?>
</form>
</div>
<?php
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `<form method="post" action="http://192.168.2.139/web/wp-admin/options.php">` to `<form method="post" action="">`

Comment: Thanks now it's working but now it's not inserting values in wp_options table

Comment: You need to add it.You have not written any code for that !

Comment: but insertion is handled by wordpress i think

Comment: Yes but for that you need to follow each and every step from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

Answer (score 1):

I have correct the code now it's working fine.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'test_plugin_setup_menu');
function test_plugin_setup_menu(){
        add_menu_page( 'Option-Man-Plugin', 'Option Man', 'manage_options', __FILE__, 'test_init' );

    add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_my_setting' );
}

function register_my_setting() {
    //register_setting( 'myoptions-group', 'my_option_name', 'intval' ); 
    register_setting('myoptions-group', 'testplugin_option1');

    register_setting('myoptions-group', 'testplugin_option2');
} 

function test_init(){
  ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <u><h2>BS3 Custom Options</h2></u>
        <form method="post" action="options.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <?php
        settings_fields('myoptions-group');
        do_settings_sections('myoptions-group');
        ?>

<input type="text"   name="testplugin_option1" value="<?php echo get_option('testplugin_option1'); ?>"/>
<input type="text"  name="testplugin_option2" value="<?php echo get_option('testplugin_option2'); ?>"/>


        <?php
      submit_button(); 
            ?>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Your field name and option name is not same and also the options page path is wrong.